# How can I configure IIS to serve my NodeJS REST API on a custom URL without opening custom ports?

Tags: node.js, express, iis, server

My organisation provide me a window server with windows server 2019 and IIS installed. I configured php, mysql to serve my site from the server using IIS.

Now I developed a new service in nodejs  that serves a REST API on local port 3000.

My organisation's security policy does not allow open custom ports for app. I want to serve my NodejS REST API through https://example.com/nodejsapp.

What if I serve NodeJS app using directory in default website or any other approach I use. Please suggest me the process.

Thanks in advance,

I tried to host separate site on IIS and stop default site. Then my NodeJS App is working fine.

Comment: "I am aware that I can not host multiple sites on same port" is a mistake, so the rest of your question is invalid. IIS allows you to host as many sites as you want on port 80/443, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html#background That's the very basic any IIS user should study on day 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the REST API on port 3000 by entering https://example.com/nodejsapp (ie default port 443) in the browser address bar, you can use reverse proxy and URL rewriting in IIS.

Please refer to this blog for specific steps: [Setup IIS with URL Rewrite as a reverse proxy for real world apps](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/setup-iis-with-url-rewrite-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-real-world/ba-p/846222)

Comment: Should I need to open port 3000 for public networks. As I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: No, you don't need to open port 3000 for the public network. In the method of using IIS as a reverse proxy, your Node.js application will be accessed through the standard HTTPS port (443) instead of port 3000. When you configure reverse proxy rules in IIS, incoming requests to https://example.com/nodejsapp are internally redirected to your Node.js application running on port 3000.